# Angular 6: Circular dependency detected, avoid it when needing both to be associated

Tags: typescript

How do I do with typescript when I have a

- `Cat` which has an `owner: Person`
- `Person` which owns `pet: Cat`

### Cat

```
import {Person} from './person'
export class Cat {

    owner: Person

    constructor(){
        this.owner = new Person()
    }

}
```

### Person

```
import {Cat} from './cat'
export class Person {

    pet: Cat

    constructor(){
        this.pet = new Cat()
    }

}
```

hope there is a good solution and pattern other than workaround like having:

- both classes into the same file
- a [third class](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/01/circular-dependency-in-constructors-and-dependency-injection/)

don't say me that typescript compiler didn't think about that case :$

Comment: Should not this `import {Person} from './cat'` be `import {Person} from './person'`

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a stackblitz? I tried in [this one](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q4hfnk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) but it appears to work without a problem.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't stop you from doing this, where exactly are you getting this error? TypeScript types disappear after compilation so circular dependency disappears as long as you don't instantiate or use instanceOf for each other.

Comment: Thx to all, what would have helped me is to point out that when the creator of both calls a creation of the other it causes a circular dependency. (See my answer)

Answer (score 0):

I find my error which was creating an instance of `Cat` into the `Person` and an instance if `Person` into `Cat` classes

So to avoid this redundency which is obviously caused by creating a

```
cat => which creates a Person => which creates a Cat => which creates a Person => ad eternam...
```

I moved the instance creation of Cat and Person

- into a different method
- or passing it to the constructor can do the trick too

  constructor (anOwner: Person){
      this.owner = anOwner
  }

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enatwj) example